# If we have exactly $8$ Sylow 7 subgroups, Show that there exits a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ s.t. the index $[G:N]$ is divisible by 56 but not 49.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group which has exactly eight Sylow 7 subgroups. Show that there exits a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that the index $[G:N]$ is divisible by 56 but not by 49.

Now this is my first mode of thinking, if we have exactly one Sylow 7 subgroup and we know that there exits a subgroup of order 56, then I'm assuming that we would mean that we would have to have $56=2^3*7$ in order for this to be true. If it is to be a normal subgroup, then there must only exist one Sylow p-subgroup. I'm still working on how to show this but this is all I have so far.

Comment: Consider the action by conjugation of $G$ on the $8$ Sylow $7$-subgroups, and let $N$ be the kernel of this action.

Comment: @DerekHolt, is there a way to solve it without using group actions? I'm not as familiar with that

Comment: I cannot think of any other way of solving this particular problem, and it looks to me as though this is the intended solution. You should learn about group actions which are fundamental to group theory.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can sensibly study Sylow's theorems and applications without using group actions. The standard proofs involve group actions, and textbooks generally cover groups actions before Sylow's theorems.

Comment: @DerekHolt Doesn't the simple group of order $\;168\;$ has exactly eight Sylow $\;7$-subgroups?

Comment: @Timbuc: Correct. That simple group also has a normal subgroup of index divisible by 56 but not by 49 :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Indeed. That was already covered in other, newer, post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is based on a basic fact about finite groups.

**Theorem** Let $H \subseteq G$ be a subgroup of index $n$. Then $G/core_G(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$.

**Proof** See I.M. Isaacs, *Finite Group Theory*, [Theorem 1.1](http://books.google.nl/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). Note, $core_G(H):=\bigcap_{g \in G}H^g$, which is a *normal* subgroup contained in $H$.

Now let us have a look at the question. Let $P \in Syl_7(G)$ and put $H=N_G(P)$ and $N=core_G(H)$. Then the Theorem tells us that $G/N$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_8$. The order of the latter is $8 \cdot 7 \cdot6 \cdots 1$, hence $49$ cannot divide index$[G:N]$. We are done when we can show that $7$ divides index$[G:N]$. Assume the contrary, then the canonical image in $G/N$ of the Sylow $7$-subgroup $P$ would be trivial: $PN/N=\{\bar{1}\}$. This means $P \subseteq N$. Now apply the Frattini Argument - it follows that $G=NN_G(P)=NH=H$ (remember $N \subseteq H$). But this implies that $P \unlhd G$, and hence $\#Syl_7(G)=1$, a contradiction to $\#Syl_7(G)=8$.

Comment: But theorem $1$ is a result of group action :)

Comment: The question is from the Wisconsin Qualifying Exams in Algebra, Problem 6, January 17th, 1983, http://math.library.wisc.edu/reserves/exams/algebra/alg8301.pdf. I do not think that the students at that time had to solve it without group actions. How would one prove the Sylow theorems then? The theorem quoted from Isaacs' book is the very first theorem of that book. And by the way, conjugation is also a group action. And we do not want to put that away too. By the way, Isaacs was a professor at the Univ. of Wisconsin @Madison.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, $G$ acts transitively by conjugation on the set $\operatorname{Syl}_7(G)$, where $|\operatorname{Syl}_7(G)|=8$. Therefore, there's a homomorphism $\varphi\colon G \rightarrow \operatorname{Sym}(\operatorname{Syl}_7(G))$, whence (First Homomorphism Theorem):

$$G/\operatorname{ker}\varphi \cong \operatorname{im}\varphi \le \operatorname{Sym}(\operatorname{Syl}_7(G)) \tag 1$$

and thence (Lagrange Theorem):

$$[G:\operatorname{ker}\varphi]=|G/\operatorname{ker}\varphi| \mid 8! \tag 2$$

Now, by contrapositive, let's suppose $49 \mid [G:\operatorname{ker}\varphi]$; thence, by $(2)$, $49\mid8!$: contradiction. Therefore, $49 \nmid [G:\operatorname{ker}\varphi]$. So, if we prove that $56 \mid [G:\operatorname{ker}\varphi]$, then take $N=\operatorname{ker}\varphi$, and we are done. To this aim, let's remind that ($\operatorname{Stab}(P)=N_G(P)$):

$$\ker\varphi=\bigcap_{P\in {\rm{Syl}_7(G)}}N_G(P) \tag 3$$

Therefore:

\begin{alignat}{1}
56 \mid [G:\operatorname{ker}\varphi] &\iff 56 \mid \frac{|G|}{|\bigcap_{P\in {\rm{Syl}_7(G)}}N_G(P)|} \\
\tag 4
\end{alignat}

Now, by the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem:

$$8\cdot|N_G(Q)|=|G|, \forall Q \in \operatorname{Syl}_7(G) \tag 5$$

and thence:

\begin{alignat}{1}
56 &\mid \frac{|G|}{|\bigcap_{P\in {\rm{Syl}_7(G)}}N_G(P)|} \iff \\
56 &\mid \frac{|G|}{|N_G(Q)|}\cdot\frac{|N_G(Q)|}{|\bigcap_{P\in {\rm{Syl}_7(G)}}N_G(P)|} \iff \\
56 &\mid 8\cdot\frac{|N_G(Q)|}{|\bigcap_{P\in {\rm{Syl}_7(G)}}N_G(P)|} \iff \\
7 &\mid \frac{|N_G(Q)|}{|\bigcap_{P\in {\rm{Syl}_7(G)}}N_G(P)|} \\
\tag 6
\end{alignat}

But this latter holds as a corollary ($p=7$) of this general:

**Lemma**. Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ a prime divisor of $|G|$ and $\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$ the set of the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. Assume further that $|\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)|>1$. Then:

$$p \mid \frac{|N_G(Q)|}{|\bigcap_{P\in {\rm{Syl}}_p(G)}N_G(P)|}, \space\forall Q \in \operatorname{Syl}_p(G) \tag 7$$

*Proof*. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3595775/810157) and the therein accepted answer. $\space\space\space\Box$

So $N:=\operatorname{ker}\varphi$ is the sought normal subgroup of $G$.