# Does $p \mid \frac{|{\rm{Stab}}(Q)|}{|\bigcap_{P\in {\rm{Syl}}_p(G)}{\rm{Stab}}(P)|}, \space\forall Q \in \operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, sylow-theory

Ancillary to the main problem I'm trying to solve, I've come up to a partial result whose generalization *would* read as follows:

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ a prime divisor of $|G|$ and $\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$ the set of the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. Assume further that $|\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)|>1$. With reference to the transitive action of $G$ by conjugacy on $\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$, the following holds:
>
> $$p \mid \frac{|{\rm{Stab}}(Q)|}{|\bigcap_{P\in {\rm{Syl}}_p(G)}{\rm{Stab}}(P)|}, \space\forall Q \in \operatorname{Syl}_p(G) \tag 1$$

So far I couldn't prove it nor find a counterexample.

---

Just for the records, I'm using $(1)$ to prove that, if $G$ has eight $7$-Sylow subgroups, then $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ such that $56$ divides $[G:N]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $|G| = p^km$ withe $p$ not dividing $m$. Since $Q \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$, we have $p^k$ divides $|{\rm Stab}(Q)| = |N_G(Q)|$.

If the result was false then $p^k$ would also divide $|R|$ where $R$ is the intersection of the normalizers of all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. But then $R$ would contain a Sylow $p$-subgroup, say $P$, of $G$, and then you would have $P$ normalizing all Sylow $p$-subgroups, which is impossible because one Sylow $p$-subgroup cannot normalize a different Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: Ha, thanks Derek, excellent! As always ... +1 from me!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is correct. If I understand you well: $Stab(Q)$ is the stabilizer subgroup of $Q$ for the conjugation by $Q$ on $Syl_p(G)$, hence $Stab(Q)=Q$. And in general for $P \in Syl_p(G)$, one has $Stab(P)=N_Q(P)=P \cap Q$. Hence your quotient equals 
$$\frac{|Q|}{|\bigcap_{P \in Syl_p(G)} Stab(P)|}=\frac{|Q|}{|\bigcap_{P \in Syl_p(G)} (P \cap Q)|}=\frac{|Q|}{|O_p(G) \cap Q|}.$$
And this quotient equals $1$ if and only if $Q=O_p(G)$, that is, when $Q$ is normal, contradicting $|Syl_p(G)| \gt 1$.

Comment: I was thinking the OP meant $\mathrm{Stab}(P) = N_G(P)$ (not just the subgroup of $Q$ with that property).

Comment: Yes, @TobErnack has anticipated me, I meant what he has written here above.

Comment: Ah, OK, then it is becoming a different matter, need to study this. This post probably helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680135/what-is-the-intersection-of-all-sylow-p-subgroups-normalizer. Because now you are looking at $\frac{|N_G(Q)|}{|R|}$, where $R$ is the intersection of all normalizers of all Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18467/normalizing-every-sylow-p-subgroup-versus-centralizing-every-sylow-p-subgroup

Comment: Thank you, in the meantime I'll go through the links and in case revert to you.